# Formik Field not triggering onChange function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

Below is my formik field, I want to trigger onChange (or onKeyUp) event to perform some operation. I tried solutions provided in previous questions related to the same problem but nothing working out for me so far. Can you please help what is going wrong here?

```
<Formik
initialValues={{
    jobId:"45445";
}}
onSubmit={(data, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setSubmitting(true);
    console.log(data);
    setSubmitting(false);
}}
onBlur={(data) => {
    // setSubmitting(true);
    console.log(data);
    // setSubmitting(false);
}}

onChange={(e) => {
    // setSubmitting(true);
    console.log('onChage', e);
    // setSubmitting(false);
}} >
{({
    values,
    isSubmitting,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    handleSubmit,
}) => (

        <Form onKeyUp={handleBlur}>

            <Button type="submit"></Button>
            <Field
                name="jobId"
                label="Job ID"
               // InputProps={{ onBlur: handleBlur }} tried not working
               onKeyUp={handleChange}tried not working
                value={values.jobId}
                as={TextFieldOutLined}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo

```
oChange={(e) => {
    // setSubmitting(true);
    console.log('onChage', e);
    // setSubmitting(false);
}}
```

It should be `onChange`

Comment: Changed it to onChange (edited the question), it is not getting called :(

Comment: Try by removiing the   onKeyUp={handleBlur} from <Form>